# Why do certain redirects cause Nexus Chrome browser to not run Javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, redirect

On the Chrome 18.0.1025469 browser for Nexus 7, 4.2.2. certain redirects seem to cause Javascript not to load.

For example the following page: http://jsfiddle.net/NTEQF/show/
has the javascript

```
alert(1)
```

On my nexus I see the the alert if I type in the following:

> jsfiddle.net/NTEQF/show/

But if I type in  (with a clear cache)

> www.jsfiddle.net/NTEQF/show/

I can see the url redirect to `jsfiddle.net/NTEQF/show/` but I see no alert.

Once I visit the page a few times, the alert starts to show up. To reproduce the no alert consistently, I can clear all the data through the devices setting panel: `Apps > All > Chrome > Clear Data` - Sometime clearing the cache through the privacy settings within Chrome does the trick too.

This means that there are situations where pages can load as if you have Javascript disabled when it is enabled. Any ideas as to what causes this or how to fix it aside from not using redirects? I have seen the issue both on redirects that remove and add `www`.

Answer (score 0):

You must be consistent with redirects.

If you call `www.whateverpage.com` on one redirect and then just `whateverpage.com` on another, you are actually going to two different domains, so any cookies or session cookies might be set for one domain but not the other. This is true also if you have for example a page like `mobile.whateverpage.com`. These are all different domains, so you'll have to treat them accordingly.